# Rails bundle install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am trying to make a new rails app when typing:

```
rails new app
```

I then get the error:

```
Could not find sqlite3-1.3.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I then run bundle install and get this error:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot      continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have
sqlite3 (1.3.10)
sqlite3-full (1.3.9.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)

I have no idea why the install wants to use 1.3.8 when I have 1.3.10 installed. I am new to rails but I have made a few small apps in the past few weeks, This is the first time this has happened to me. Is there A local Gem file that I could edit so when I create A new app it doesn't try to use this old gem. I have also tried to create a new app use postgres with the same error.

I am using mac osx 10.10.1. ruby version 2.2.1.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
when I run

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'
```

this is the result:

./sqlite3_ruby.h:16:36: note: expanded from macro 'RBIGNUM_LEN'
 #define RBIGNUM_LEN(x) RBIGNUM(x)->len

~~~~~~~~~~  ^

statement.c:261:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SIZEOF_BDIGITS'
      if (RBIGNUM_LEN(value) * SIZEOF_BDIGITS <= 8) {
                               ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [statement.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Comment: what happens if you run `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'`?

Comment: The same issue happens as bundle install. An error has occurred installing

Comment: Can you please paste the result of `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Gemfile` and `GemFile.lock` to see if the versions are fixed. Remove the version or change it as necessary.

Comment: Where are these file locally? I know where they are when an app is generated but not before . Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

Delete your gemfile.lock
Run `bundle install`.

If bundle install still fails, run `gem uninstall sqlite3`
and run `bundle install`

Gemfile and Gemfile.lock is located in the root folder of your file

Comment: I do not have an app file structure yet so I don't know how to delete the gemfile.lock file. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Run `gem uninstall sqlite3` and then `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8' `. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your app folder structure to this:

[image]

Note the folder structure and where the `Gemfile` is located. Inside the `Gemfile`, there are several gems or plugins for the different software dependencies that are typically required in a new Rails app. Open the `Gemfile` and inspect the file and look for sqlite3. Modify the version number next to the sqlite3 to match `'1.3.8'`. Example:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
```

**EDIT:**

I suggest uninstalling/removing all instances of sqlite3 and following these instructions:

1. Ensure you have latest version of rubygems: `gem update --system`
2. Uninstall sqlite3
3. Install sqlite3: `gem install sqlite3`
4. Check install version: `gem list sqlite3`
5. Run `rails new appappapp`

Comment: I am unable to generate a new rails application. So I do not have that file structure yet. Thanks for the reply